# Django form not passing is_valid() test

Tags: python, django, forms

In my Django app in a Createview class it never enters the is_valid(): statement and I can not seem to find any errors:

## models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings
from .validators import validate_file_extension
import zipfile
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140) 
    body = models.TextField(max_length=250)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    album_image = models.FileField(validators=[validate_file_extension])
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1)
    face = models.IntegerField(default=1)   

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('photos:detail',kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

## views.py

This is my view folder that contains a list view a detailed view and create view. Although the form doesnt pass the valid test, it still gets uploaded and is viewable by the user

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from .forms import PostForm
from .models import Post
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.template import loader
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
import cognitive_face as CF
import json

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name='photos/post.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'photos/detail.html'

class PostCreate(generic.CreateView):
    form = PostForm()
    model = Post

    if form.is_valid():
        print('valid')
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        album_image = form.cleaned_data['album_image']

        instance.save()
    if not form.is_valid():
        print('not')
```

## post_form.html

```
<html>
<body>
{% if request.user.is_authenticated%}
<h3>Hello {{request.user.username}}, please upload your image as either a .JPEG, .GIF or .PNG</h3>
{% endif %}
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                   {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
             <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                {{form.as_p}}
                {{ form.errors }}
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
        {% else %}
        <p>You must be logged in to upload a file</p>
                {% endif %}
        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>

</html>
```

## urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from photos.models import Post
from . import views

app_name = 'photos'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'post/add/$', views.PostCreate.as_view(), name='post-add'),
]
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the response (i.e.: `form.errors` has data)?

Comment: No, if i print(len(form.errors)) I get zero

Comment: @LukeCollins seems like `PostCreate` code is incomplete/confusing, your form checking code is inside a class def ?

Comment: I dont believe it is incomplete, or if it is I do not know what is missing. Yes it is inside a Class is this wrong?

Comment: When do you think that code will be ran currently?

Comment: When the user goes to photos/post/add.. I will edit the post to contain the urls too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing function based view code inside a class based view, which is incorrect.

You shouldn't need to instantiate the form, or manually check whether it is valid. Just set `form_class` for the view, then override `form_valid` or `form_invalid` if you need to change the behaviour when the form is valid or invalid. Since you have `{{ form.errors }}` in your template, it should show any errors when you submit the form.

```
class PostCreate(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = PostForm
    model = Post
```

See the docs on [form handling with class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#form-handling-with-class-based-views) for more information. You might find it easier to write a [function based view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#the-view) to begin with, since the flow of the code is easier to follow.

Comment: I have changed to a function based view.

Comment: In my models I have a `face' field, that I would like to change the value of in response to something that happens with the user upload, but I cant seem to be able to change the value of it? any thought

Comment: After saving the form with `instance = form.save(commit=False)`, change the value of `instance.face` before calling `instance.save()`. If you're still stuck, it would be better to ask a new question because it's a different issue.

Comment: Thank you so much!!